# Designing PI controller

Tags: matlab, controls

```matlab
% Define the transfer function
num = [1e-6, 1.314e-9, 2.66e-13];
den = [1, 0.000163, 5.272e-7, 3.538e-11];
G = tf(num, den);
Kp = 10;
Ki = 20;

C = pid(Kp,Ki);
C = tunablePID('C','pi');

% Construct the PID controller
silas = feedback(G*C,1);
pidtune(silas)
```

I wanted to design a PI controller using the defined transfer function, and I wanted to be able to tune the values of `kp` and `ki`. A quick internet search told me to use `tunablePID`. I tested it, but it seems I used it wrongly. It runs alright, but it doesn't open in the PIDtunner app which would have allowed me to change the parameters.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). TL;DR: never. We're volunteers answering when and only if we want. Your deadlines are of no concern to us. If you want something done yesterday, hire a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [PID Tuner App](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pidtuner-app.html). In MATLAB, navigate to the Apps tab and select the PID Tuner. Import your plant `G` and set the controller to *PI*.

Comment: that worked pefectly